# Change location of MathJax Javascript in AsciiDoctor-generated HTML

Tags: mathjax, asciidoctor

I'm trying to create a set of HTML files that can be accessed offline, and therefore avoid using CDNs for hosting CSS and Javascript files. Unfortunately, I've found no way of specifying the location of the MathJax files when using `-a stem=latexmath`. Is there some configuration value for this available?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a way to do this without creating your own converter. You can track this issue at https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/761. It is also scheduled for 1.5.4 and 1.6.0

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the link, I'll track that issue.